# Having Trouble Accessing Variables & Setting Up Stripe Connect (Flask)

Tags: javascript, api, flask, stripe-payments

I'm building a Flask marketplace app (using Stripe [Collect payments then pay out](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide)) where users can choose how much they want to pay (think fundraiser).

I am having trouble moving necessary data around appropriately throughout the checkout process and could really use some help.

Once a user enters how much they'd like to donate, the donation amount and the owner of the campaign they'd like to donate to are sent to the below `/pay` route where they see a form to enter in their card details with a "Submit Payment" button.

```
@app.route('/pay', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def pay():
    campaign = Campaign.query.get_or_404(request.args["campaign_id"])
    owner = User.query.get_or_404(campaign.user_id) #owner of the campaign
    donation_amount = request.args['amount_entered'] # EX: "1000"
    return render_template('payment_form.html', campaign=campaign, owner=owner, amount=donation_amount)
```

The file, **payment_form.html**, has a simple Stripe form like this:

```
<form method="post" id="payment-form" class="sr-payment-form">
    <div class="sr-form-row">
        <label for="card-element">Credit or debit card</label>
        <div style="width: 30em" id="card-element"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span style="width: 30em; height: 2em; letter-spacing: 0em" id="card-errors" role="alert"></span>
    </div>
    <button id="card-button" style="width: 33em;">Submit Payment</button>
</form>
```

And whenever someone enters their card info and submits the payment, I have a JavaScript file that listens for it and processes the payment (this does not work yet).

```
var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  fetch("/pay_now", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
      // not sure what to do here
  });
  stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
    payment_method: {
      card: card,
      billing_details: {
        name: 'Jenny Rosen' //placeholder (would like to replace)
      }
    }
  }).then(function(result) {
    if (result.error) {
      console.log(result.error.message);
    } else {
      if (result.paymentIntent.status === 'succeeded') {
    }
  });
});
```

This script fetches the below Flask API `/pay_now` and should return the `clientSecret` variable as well as other necessary data to complete the transaction.

```
@app.route('/pay_now', methods=['GET','POST'])
def create_payment():
    intent = stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
        payment_method_types=['card'],
        amount="1000", #need to pass dollar amount here calculated in /pay route
        currency="usd",
        transfer_data={'destination': owner.stripe_id}, #need to pass owner from /pay route
        application_fee_amount="100")
    )
    client_secret = intent.client_secret
    return jsonify({"client_secret": client_secret})
```

So basically, my dilemma is that I have the amount of the donation and the campaign owner as variables in the /pay route. But I need to access them when I create the stripe.PaymentIntent object when I call the `/pay_now API` from my JavaScript and then I need to pass the `clientSecret` variable back to my JavaScript file for `confirmCardPayment()` to actually complete the payment.

I'm also open to different approaches if mine doesn't make sense.

I am new to Stripe & new to APIs in Flask. Any help or explanation here would be extremely helpful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to only POST to your `/pay_now` route, in the body of that POST you should include the amount your user intends to donate. Then it's a simple case of including that amount when creating the PaymentIntent and returning the client secret to be confirmed on the client.

You might want to first do some checks on both the client and server whether the amount makes sense (e.g. if someone enters -1 it correctly gets rejected).

The `stripe.confirmCardPayment` code should go in the `then` resolver of your `fetch` request, after the response has been parsed to JSON:

```
fetch("/pay_now", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({
      amount: amount, // get this from the form
    }),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    stripe.confirmCardPayment(data.clientSecret, {
      payment_method: {
        card: card,
        billing_details: {
          name: name, // get this from the form, like you did with the amount
        }
      }
    })
  .then(function(result) {
    if (result.error) {
      console.log(result.error.message);
    } else {
      if (result.paymentIntent.status === 'succeeded') {
        // display success message
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I do have a couple follow up questions... How do I get the `amount` variable from the `/pay` route to the JavaScript file? I know how to get it into the html by using Jinja, but unsure how to actually use the variable in the JavaScript. Also, can you explain why we use POST instead of GET? We're sending data to the route `/pay_now` but we're also fetching the `client_secret` because we need it in the JavaScript for the stripe.confirmPayment().